# PyQt5 GUI with Keras model that runs in a separate thread, stucks when "run" button is pressed again

Tags: matplotlib, keras, pyqt5, qthread

i have an application that receives .pickle file with labeled train data, and should build a neural network (with Keras). It should train on the data, and show the train/validation errors live on a canvas with matplotlib and show the progress with the QprogressBar.

I have a custom callback that sends a pyqtSignal to the main GUI on each epoch end, sending the current epoch and the cumulative train and validation errors. Then in the main program there is a function that receives the signal and triggers the update method.

Everything works fine until I press on the GUI window - then the app stucks (but the net still runs in the shell). I guess the click interrupt triggers some loop that makes the whole program freeze, but i could"nt figure out which.

I"ve searched other questions regarding the PyQt5 GUI being stuck when using threads, but did"t find an answer - [here](https://nikolak.com/pyqt-threading-tutorial/)

I"ve tried to use Qthread.start() instead of Qthread.run() for the Qthread - but in this case the plots don"t update at all.

I"ve written a complete example to demonstrate the problem (the data file should be in .pickle format and contain a list [X, y] of X - samples as a numpy ndarray, and y - the corresponding labels as numpy ndarray and can be found at https://www.kaggle.com/luciferadmin/heart-disease-uci-in-pickle-format) :

```
import sys
import os
import pickle as pkl
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.models import Model
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QProgressBar, QWidget, QVBoxLayout, QPushButton, QLineEdit, QFileDialog
from PyQt5.QtCore import QThread, pyqtSignal
import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (QSizePolicy)
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')


class Plot(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, x_label, y_label, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)

        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.compute_initial_figure()
        self.axes.set_xlabel(x_label)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(y_label)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QSizePolicy.Expanding, QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.set_xticks(range(1, 100, 10))


class MultiPlot(Plot):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, x_axis_name='X', y_axis_name='Y', width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        super().__init__(x_axis_name, y_axis_name, parent, width, height, dpi)
        self.compute_initial_figure()

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.set_xticks(range(0, 100, 10))

    def plot_multi_data(self, x_axis_name='X', y_axis_name='Y', plot_labels=None, y_list=None):
        if y_list is not None:
            self.axes.clear()

            graph_handles = []

            markers = ['b:', 'r']
            y_index = 0

            for y in y_list:

                x = range(1, len(y) + 1)
                label = plot_labels[y_index]

                new_plot, = self.axes.plot(x, y, markers[y_index], markersize=2, label=label)
                graph_handles.append(new_plot)
                y_index += 1

                self.axes.set_xticks(x, int(len(list(x))/10))
            self.axes.legend(handles=graph_handles, loc=0, fontsize=8, shadow=True)

        self.axes.set_xlabel(x_axis_name)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(y_axis_name)

        self.draw()


class TrainPlotCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        Callback.__init__(self)
        self.train_err = []
        self.val_err = []
        self.signal = signal

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.train_err.append(1 - logs.get('acc'))
        self.val_err.append(1 - logs.get('val_acc'))

        self.signal.emit(epoch, [self.train_err, self.val_err])


def classification_model(data_input_path, on_epoch_end_signal):

    # ///////////////////// TEST /////////////////////
    if os.path.exists(data_input_path):
        plot_losses = TrainPlotCallback(on_epoch_end_signal)
        with open(data_input_path, 'rb') as pickle_in:
            data = pkl.load(pickle_in)
            X = data[0]
            y = data[1]

        input_size = X.shape[1]

        # MODEL CREATION
        # ///////////////////// INPUT LAYER /////////////////////
        inputs = Input(shape=(input_size,))
        # ///////////////////// INPUT LAYER /////////////////////
        # ///////////////////// HIDDEN LAYER /////////////////////
        x = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(inputs)   # THE FIRST LAYER
        # ///////////////////// HIDDEN LAYER /////////////////////
        # ///////////////////// OUTPUT LAYERS /////////////////////
        predictions = Dense(len(y[0]), activation='softmax')(x)  # the length of the output layer is as the length of the classes being predicted.
        # ///////////////////// OUTPUT LAYERS /////////////////////
        # MODEL CREATION

        # ///////////////////// MODEL DEFINITION /////////////////////
        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
        model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
                      loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      metrics=['acc'])
        # ///////////////////// MODEL DEFINITION /////////////////////

        # ///////////////////// MODEL TRAINING /////////////////////
        model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=100, epochs=100, callbacks=[plot_losses])
        # ///////////////////// MODEL TRAINING /////////////////////


class ModelThread(QThread):
    epoch_end_signal = pyqtSignal(int, list)  # signal that has epoch # as the first parameter, and a list that contains the error values for the train and validation.

    def __init__(self, data_input_path):
        QThread.__init__(self)
        self.data_input_path = data_input_path

    def __del__(self):
        self.wait()

    def run(self):
        classification_model(data_input_path=self.data_input_path,
                             on_epoch_end_signal=self.epoch_end_signal
                             )


class DashBoard(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_v_box = QVBoxLayout(self)

        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< STRINGS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        self.input_data_path_str = ''
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< STRINGS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PROGRESS BAR >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        self.progress_bar = QProgressBar()
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< PROGRESS BAR >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< BUTTONS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        self.run_model_btn = QPushButton('Run')
        self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn = QPushButton('Browse')
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< BUTTONS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< MULTI PLOTS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        self.in_training_plot = MultiPlot(x_axis_name='Epoch Number', y_axis_name='Error')
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< MULTI PLOTS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< LINE EDITS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        self.train_data_file_path_le = QLineEdit()
        #  <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< LINE EDITS >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
        self.init()
        self.pack()
        self.showMaximized()

    def init(self):
        self.progress_bar.hide()
        self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_click)
        self.run_model_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_click)

    def pack(self):
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.train_data_file_path_le)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.in_training_plot)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.run_model_btn)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

    def on_btn_click(self):
        btn_index = self.sender()

        if btn_index == self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn:
            self.input_data_path_str = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, '.pickle files', os.getenv('HOME'), '*.pickle')[0]
            self.train_data_file_path_le.setText(self.input_data_path_str)
        elif btn_index == self.run_model_btn:
            model_thread = ModelThread(data_input_path=self.input_data_path_str)
            model_thread.epoch_end_signal.connect(self.update_ui_on_epoch_end)
            self.progress_bar.show()
            model_thread.run()
            self.progress_bar.hide()

    def update_ui_on_epoch_end(self, current_epoch_num, error_lists):
        if current_epoch_num < 100:
            self.progress_bar.setValue(current_epoch_num)
        else:
            self.progress_bar.setValue(100)
        self.in_training_plot.plot_multi_data(x_axis_name='Epoch', y_axis_name='Error', plot_labels=['Train Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy'], y_list=[error_lists[0], error_lists[1]])

    def run_model(self):
        if os.path.exists(self.train_data_file_path_str) and os.path.exists(self.output_data_path_str):
            train_thread = ModelThread(data_input_path='')
            train_thread.epoch_end_signal.connect(self.update_ui_on_epoch_end)
            # train_thread.start()
            self.progress_bar.show()
            train_thread.run()
            self.progress_bar.hide()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_menu = DashBoard()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: share your .pickle file

Comment: the dataset can be found in the kaggle.com - https://www.kaggle.com/luciferadmin/heart-disease-uci-in-pickle-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your initial error is that you should not call run directly but start, but your thread is a local variable that will be removed a moment later.

Instead of creating a custom QThread a better solution is to create a QObject that lives in another thread and invoke the function using QTimer.singleShot.

```
import os
import sys
from functools import partial
import pickle as pkl
from keras.layers import Input, Dense
from keras.callbacks import Callback
from keras.models import Model

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

import matplotlib
matplotlib.use('Qt5Agg')

from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

class Plot(FigureCanvas):
    def __init__(self, x_label, y_label, parent=None, width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        fig = Figure(figsize=(width, height), dpi=dpi)

        self.axes = fig.add_subplot(111)

        self.compute_initial_figure()
        self.axes.set_xlabel(x_label)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(y_label)

        FigureCanvas.__init__(self, fig)
        self.setParent(parent)

        FigureCanvas.setSizePolicy(self, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding)

        FigureCanvas.updateGeometry(self)

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.set_xticks(range(1, 100, 10))


class MultiPlot(Plot):
    def __init__(self, parent=None, x_axis_name='X', y_axis_name='Y', width=5, height=4, dpi=100):
        super().__init__(x_axis_name, y_axis_name, parent, width, height, dpi)
        self.compute_initial_figure()

    def compute_initial_figure(self):
        self.axes.set_xticks(range(0, 100, 10))

    def plot_multi_data(self, x_axis_name='X', y_axis_name='Y', plot_labels=None, y_list=None):
        if y_list is not None:
            self.axes.clear()

            graph_handles = []

            markers = ['b:', 'r']
            y_index = 0

            for y in y_list:

                x = range(1, len(y) + 1)
                label = plot_labels[y_index]

                new_plot, = self.axes.plot(x, y, markers[y_index], markersize=2, label=label)
                graph_handles.append(new_plot)
                y_index += 1

                self.axes.set_xticks(x, int(len(list(x))/10))
            self.axes.legend(handles=graph_handles, loc=0, fontsize=8, shadow=True)

        self.axes.set_xlabel(x_axis_name)
        self.axes.set_ylabel(y_axis_name)

        self.draw()


class TrainPlotCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, signal):
        Callback.__init__(self)
        self.train_err = []
        self.val_err = []
        self.signal = signal

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        self.train_err.append(1 - logs.get('acc'))
        self.val_err.append(1 - logs.get('val_acc'))
        self.signal.emit(epoch, [self.train_err, self.val_err])

def classification_model(data_input_path, on_epoch_end_signal):

    # ///////////////////// TEST /////////////////////
    if os.path.exists(data_input_path):
        plot_losses = TrainPlotCallback(on_epoch_end_signal)
        with open(data_input_path, 'rb') as pickle_in:
            data = pkl.load(pickle_in)
            X = data[0]
            y = data[1]

        input_size = X.shape[1]

        # MODEL CREATION
        # ///////////////////// INPUT LAYER /////////////////////
        inputs = Input(shape=(input_size,))
        # ///////////////////// INPUT LAYER /////////////////////
        # ///////////////////// HIDDEN LAYER /////////////////////
        x = Dense(10, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='normal')(inputs)   # THE FIRST LAYER
        # ///////////////////// HIDDEN LAYER /////////////////////
        # ///////////////////// OUTPUT LAYERS /////////////////////
        predictions = Dense(len(y[0]), activation='softmax')(x)  # the length of the output layer is as the length of the classes being predicted.
        # ///////////////////// OUTPUT LAYERS /////////////////////
        # MODEL CREATION

        # ///////////////////// MODEL DEFINITION /////////////////////
        model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=predictions)
        model.compile(optimizer='Adam',
                      loss='categorical_crossentropy',
                      metrics=['acc'])
        # ///////////////////// MODEL DEFINITION /////////////////////

        # ///////////////////// MODEL TRAINING /////////////////////
        model.fit(X, y, validation_split=0.2, batch_size=100, epochs=100, callbacks=[plot_losses])
        # ///////////////////// MODEL TRAINING /////////////////////


class Worker(QtCore.QObject):
    started = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    epoch_end_signal = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int, list)  # signal that has epoch # as the first parameter, and a list that contains the error values for the train and validation.

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str)
    def start_task(self, input_path):
        self.started.emit()
        classification_model(data_input_path=input_path,
                             on_epoch_end_signal=self.epoch_end_signal)
        self.finished.emit()


class DashBoard(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.main_v_box = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.input_data_path_str = ''
        self.progress_bar = QtWidgets.QProgressBar()
        self.run_model_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Run')
        self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Browse')
        self.in_training_plot = MultiPlot(x_axis_name='Epoch Number', y_axis_name='Error')
        self.train_data_file_path_le = QtWidgets.QLineEdit()
        self.init()
        self.pack()
        self.showMaximized()

    def init(self):
        self.worker = Worker()
        thread = QtCore.QThread(self)
        thread.start()
        self.worker.moveToThread(thread)
        self.progress_bar.hide()
        self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_click)
        self.run_model_btn.clicked.connect(self.on_btn_click)
        self.worker.epoch_end_signal.connect(self.update_ui_on_epoch_end)
        self.worker.started.connect(self.progress_bar.show)
        self.worker.finished.connect(self.progress_bar.hide)
        self.worker.started.connect(partial(self.run_model_btn.setEnabled, False))
        self.worker.finished.connect(partial(self.run_model_btn.setEnabled, True))

    def pack(self):
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.train_data_file_path_le)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.in_training_plot)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.run_model_btn)
        self.main_v_box.addWidget(self.progress_bar)

    def on_btn_click(self):
        btn_index = self.sender()

        if btn_index == self.browse_train_data_file_path_btn:
            self.input_data_path_str, _ = QtWidgets.QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, '.pickle files', os.getenv('HOME'), '*.pickle')
            self.train_data_file_path_le.setText(self.input_data_path_str)
        elif btn_index == self.run_model_btn:
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, partial(self.worker.start_task, self.input_data_path_str))

    def update_ui_on_epoch_end(self, current_epoch_num, error_lists):
        if current_epoch_num < 100:
            self.progress_bar.setValue(current_epoch_num)
        else:
            self.progress_bar.setValue(100)
        self.in_training_plot.plot_multi_data(x_axis_name='Epoch', y_axis_name='Error', plot_labels=['Train Accuracy', 'Validation Accuracy'], y_list=[error_lists[0], error_lists[1]])


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main_menu = DashBoard()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```